# IE10 - avoid form names in global scope for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I've got a web application with a search box, and an onKeypress event calls `Query.keyPress()`.  Query is defined in an included javascript file.  Most of the time this works correctly.

On IE10 from some screens, trying to use the search box gives an error:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'keyPress'
```

What I have found is some of the screens have a query form with a name and id of 'Query'.  It seems in IE10 this appears in the global scope, and overrides the object literal from the javascript.  For info, the search box is not inside this form.

I've replaced the onKeypress code with `alert(Query);` and I see `[object HTMLFormElement]` which confirms what is happening.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening on IE10?

Comment: change `Query` to `MyQuery`?

Comment: This issue has been around since IE supported scripting and "works" for element IDs too. The fix is to declare global variables.

Comment: What do you mean by declare global variables?

Comment: Eliran, of course I can do this, but I am responsible for the platform.  And with this fix, as soon as anyone writes a screen with a form called MyQuery, it will break again.

Comment: You can access it using `window["Query"]` and it hopefully will get you the correct object.

Comment: window.Query also works, and this is the workaround I am now using.  I see the form object is actually document.Query.  I'd still ideally like a way for that to not be there as it is only ever going to cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be negated by using your own namespace, rather than polluting the global scope time and time again.

```
var MY_STUFF = {};

MY_STUFF.Query = function () {};
MY_STUFF.MY_CONST = 4;
MY_STUFF.utilityFunction = function () {};
```

... this way, everything breaks if you add a form element named `MY_STUFF`, but it won't break if you add form elements called `Query`, `MY_CONST` or `utilityFunction` (not the best names, but you get the gist).

Like I said, it doesn't *fix* the problem, but it negates it. Polluting the global scope is also a bad practise.

---

You can, of course, not use a global variable at all, through closures. But this will likely require a lot of restructuring, if you have your application spread over multiple files, and no build process in place to combine your files.

```
(function () {
    var Query = function () {};

    // Query.keyPress() as much as you want!
}());

// Note you can't use it outside of the closure.
```

Comment: In fact this is already what we have done: Query itself is an object literal that wraps up everything to do with searching.  There are only around 4 or 5 of these globals left.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this should work. When declaring your variable Query, provide a var keyword before it.

```
var Query = new Object (); //right practice

Query = new Object (); //wrong practice
```